# Getting multiple values from JSON

Tags: javascript

I'm attempting to pull multiple values to create a list in the form of a string. When I am pulling my data it responds as such.

```
data = [{name: 'value'}, {name: 'value'}, {name: 'value'}]
```

I need the end product to be `"value, value, value"` although I'm unsure at the moment on how to go about this.

Comment: Please specify from where are you pulling this data. Language, Platform and all possible details you can share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use Array#Map in JavaScript.

You can see how to use it on MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=example)

```js
var data = [{name: 'value'}, {name: 'value'}, {name: 'value'}]
var result = data.map(a => a.name);

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Jesus that was easy. I've guess my search terms weren't up to snuff. Thanks!

Comment: Cool ! Glad to know that help :) don't forget to accept and upvote if it's useful for you :D

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = data.map(elem => elem.value)
```

In your case, the `data` object is an array.
You can use the `map` function, that will iterate over the array elements, it returns a new array with values from the `map` function callback